# How to add live frame around image?

Tags: image, canvas, frame, preview

i would like to accomplish something similar to the many printing gallery you see around. I need to be able to show a frame (wooden frame) aroung and image based on the size of the image. And change the kind of image based on a dropdown selection or whatever.
Where i need to start?

Comment: Maybe show some examples. Maybe say what platform you use. What languages you are familiar with. Whether desktop or web-based. Show what you have so far... that sort of thing.

Comment: ok sorry.
Something like that: http://fineartamerica.com/products/a-world-less-serious-simone-pompei-framed-print.html or http://www.imagekind.com/Minimalist-Muppets_art?IMID=f4cae013-3105-42d4-b7d3-7b3b9da467f6

The problem is that i don't know where to start.

I would like to integrate it in a gravity form/woocommerce environment but this is something i will take care of. I just need to understand where to start.
Thank you

Comment: Check out 9-slice scaling.